# tar extract hangs on non-existent file

Tags: tar

I tried to extract a valid tar gzip file, P.tgz. It hangs infinitely.

```
tar -x P.tgz
```

This archive is of very small size. But it never gets completed.

I tried with a non-existent tar archive, `DoesntExist.tgz`. It doesn't report an error message, `"archive doesn't exist"` and it hangs infinitely, never returning to shell prompt.

Note: `P.tgz` is a valid gzip file created using the command,

```
tar -cPf P.tgz /opt/seckie
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tar` doesn't take the name of the tar file as an argument. The name of the tar file can be passed as an argument to the `-f` option. You can write

```
tar -x -f P.tgz
```

or (`tar` has some weird option parsing for historical reasons)

```
tar xf P.tgz
```

or (if `tar` doesn't see the name of the tar file, you need to tell it explicitly that it's compressed)

```
tar xz <P.tgz
```

GNU tar defaults to reading the tar file from standard input (or writing it to standard output, for commands that create a tar file). Most other tar implementations default to reading from tape. When you run `tar -x P.tgz`, the `tar` program waits for the archive on its standard input. It waits forever since you never supply any input. The argument `P.tgz` is the name of a file to extract from the archive.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected it by using,

```
tar xf P.tgz  #added f to the options
```

All archive file name arguments must be following, f option, it looks like...